# Passing an Object to swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, object, user-interface, initialization

I have 5-6 GUIs(seperate classes) one opens another according to their functionality, every GUI takes an object inside, I pass the final Object in a flight booking system like this to my GUI when a JButton "Book" is clicked from the seat selection menu in Book_GUI.java

```
Passenger_GUI frameP = new Passenger_GUI(eco.seats[x][z].getMyPassenger());
frameP.setVisible(true);    
eco.seats[x][z].setBooked(true);
```

in Passenger_GUI.java I have:

```
        private Passenger passenger_GUI;
```

later in Constructor without initializing `passenger_GUI` I assign the input Passenger Object to it:

```
public Passenger_GUI(Passenger myPassenger) {
    passenger_GUI = myPassenger;
```

Everything works no errors... I have 2 questions, do I have to initialize first passenger_GUI and then make the assigment or is it not necessary?
Second important question; the changes I make in the Passenger_GU to object myPassenger(`eco.seats[x][z].myPassenger`), will they be saved in the previous GUI `Book_GUI.java` I think not because the Passenger_GUI class does not have a return value... or am I wrong?How can I make the changes I apply on an Object stable and be used for the future in `Book_GUI.java`?(previous GUI)
Thank you for your time!

Here full classes:
http://www.copypastecode.com/643018/
http://www.copypastecode.com/643022/

Comment: Please can you put here all of related code for understanding of question?

Comment: @SeniorJD Updated the Question with links to source full class codes.

Comment: *"I have 5-6 GUIs .. one opens another according to their functionality"*  1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok I exaggerated I only have 3 GUIs Main_GUI, Book_GUI and Passenger_GUI, I was worried about passing the object from one to another but I see that it works and the changes are applied to the object, thanks for the links as well SSCCE looks very useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, you can just initialize `passenger_GUI` in your constructor.
2. The changes should persist. Since you're passing an `Object` and not a primitive to your `Passenger_GUI` constructor, Java actually passes a reference to that `Passenger` object. Your `Passenger_GUI.passenger_GUI` field should refer to the same object (and indeed, the same location in memory) as `eco.seats[x][z].getMyPassenger()`, so any changes made to that object from within `Passenger_GUI` should also be visible from `Book_GUI`.

Comment: I didnt understand the first answer, I put my full code in the question to the end, my Passenger class is without a constructor.So passenger_GUI is never being initialized.But still works is this valid or should I have made : 
`passenger_GUI = new Passenger();`
`passenger_GUI = myPassenger;` ?

Comment: You're already doing what I said in my answer to #1. You're passing an already-existing Passenger object to your Passenger_GUI constructor: `Passenger_GUI frameP = new Passenger_GUI(eco.seats[x][z].getMyPassenger());`. Then the constructor is taking this object and assigning it to the `passenger_GUI` field. This initializes `passenger_GUI`. You don't need to also initialize it outside the constructor.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use `new` to initialize something. You just need to assign it to some value, which you're doing in your constructor already.

Comment: I just made a test if the name I entered for the Passenger is visible in previous GUI and it works so all you said and I assumed was true :) thanks for clarifying!Sometimes compilers dont give errors for invalid statements... thats why I just wanted to be sure!